# Does Ubuntu support Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) for android emulator?

Tags: kernel

Why Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM) for android emulator does not exist for Ubuntu and only exist for Mac OS and Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supported for Ubuntu, see [Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager):

> The following platforms are supported by the Intel HAXM:
>
> Windows 8 and 8.1 (32/64-bit), Windows 7 (32/64-bit), Windows Vista*
>   (32/64-bit)
>
> Mac OS X* 10.6 (32/64-bit) or 10.7 (32/64-bit) or 10.8 (64-bit) or
>   10.9 (64-bit)
>
> **Ubuntu (64-bit)**